# Css Animations: trial to mvoe a div element up and down and simultaneously rotating the img element inside it fails

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Project Description: I am in quest to apply two animations to a nested images inside a div that actually **The Div** has the responsibility to move the image up and down because the image is captivated inside it **And** the image(img) which is nested inside the div, **Has the responsibility to rotate successively** while **the div is bouncing the image up and down**.

**What I want**:

1.the image inside the div should keep rotating 360 degrees

2.While the **1** is happening, The div should keep bouncing or moving up and down

```css
.ground {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: gray;
 top: 800px;
}
.ball-container {
 position: relative;
 width 100px;
 height: 100px;
 left: 50%;
 animation-name: bounce;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-direction: forwards;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce{
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 50% {
  top: 700px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 70px;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
 }
}
img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 animation-name: rotation;
 animation-direction: forwards;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes rotation {
 from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<html>
 <div class="ball-container" id="ball-container"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53283.svg" alt="ball" class="ball" id="ball"/>
 </div>
 <div class="ground"></div>
</html>
```

**The problem:** **the bouncing process is awesome, but I dont know how to make the image rotating while it is bouncing.**

Thanks.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/real_m_vahedi/pen/BaoojbE?editors=1100)

---

**THE POST IS EDITED AND HAS NO PROBLEM AFTER APPLYING THE ANSWER**

Comment: `img{animation-iteration-count: infinite;}` should fix it

Comment: @NikosM., Unfortunately Does'nt work , have you tried it ?

Comment: well the problem is that animation is done only once and then stops, while your box is still bouncing. That is the problem, so you need to run the rotate animation as many times as bounce animation, that is infinite

Comment: @NikosM., I fixed it ,but the image still doesnt rotate ?!, you can review the post again.

Comment: ytou have a typo `to {transform: rotate(360deg;)}` the semicolon should be outside

Comment: also `animation-direction: forwards` is invalid, `animation-direction: normal` is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

animation-iteration-count should be infinite on img rotation, to match the number of times it bounces as well, else the animation will run once and stop while the box is still bouncing. Also you have a typo, the semicolon in `to {transform: rotate(360deg;)}` should be outside `to {transform: rotate(360deg);}`. This is why it doesnt work.

Furthermore `animation-direction:forwards` is invalid, the correct value is `animation-direction:normal`.

With these corrections the code is:

```css
.ground {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: gray;
 top: 800px;
}
.ball-container {
 position: relative;
 width 100px;
 height: 100px;
 left: 50%;
 animation-name: bounce;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-direction: normal;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce{
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 50% {
  top: 700px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 70px;
 }
 100% {
  top: 0px;
 }
}
img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 animation-name: rotation;
 animation-direction: normal;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes rotation {
 from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<html>
 <div class="ball-container" id="ball-container"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53283.svg" alt="ball" class="ball" id="ball"/>
 </div>
 <div class="ground"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG, what a stupid mistake I did there... but did not figure out, thanks.